# "The system cannot find the path specified." on Windows while running fine on Linux

Tags: python, windows, conda, snakemake, python-venv

I cannot get a very simple example to work..
I want to create a file with a python script, which works fine when executed standalone and has the below content:

```
with open("test.txt", "w") as f:
   f.write("test")
```

However, when using it in a Snakefile like this:

```
rule all:
    input:
        "test.txt"

rule make_test:
    output:
        "test.txt"
    script:
        "create_test_txt.py"
```

and running `snakemake -c 1`, I get an error on my Windows 10 machine, "The system cannot find the path specified." which leads to snakemake failing and deleting test.txt as it was created under failing condtions.

I use conda with an environment defined by the attached "environment_win10_22H2.yaml" file.

Now, if I repeat the experiment on my Ubuntu 22.04 3 LTS virtual machine, also using conda and an environment created from the attached "environment_Ubuntu22_04_3LTS.yaml" file, this is not an issue at all, and `snakemake -c 1` succeeds without a problem.

Both "environment_Ubuntu22_04_3LTS.yaml" and "environment_win10_22H2.yaml" are derived from the same simplified but less specific "environment.yaml"

This is just a simplified example, but I found it to be the same case when trying to execute other scripts as well - and I am confused how this could fail. I also attached the log just in case.

EDIT: It seems like this is an issue with my Windows machine in particular. I ran it on another Windows machine (Win 11 in that case) and there it worked just fine. Also, the issue seems not to be restricted to snakemake or even conda. I installed python 3.11.6, created a virtual environment using `python -m venv env`. Activating it using `env\Scripts\activate` will also produce the error message "The system cannot find the path specified."
Please note, I cannot reinstall the Windows system as it is managed by my organization and not me.

EDIT2: As this problem does not let me focus on anything else, I now tried using micromamba - and this works out just fine. I guess something is up with installing a python distribution and the rights associated to it (although I did try both adminitrator enabled and user installation of python / conda).

"snakemake.log"

```
Building DAG of jobs...
Provided cores: 1 (use --cores to define parallelism)
Rules claiming more threads will be scaled down.
Job stats:
job          count
---------  -------
all              1
make_test        1
total            2

Select jobs to execute...

[Mon Nov  6 16:48:54 2023]
rule make_test:
    output: test.txt
    jobid: 1
    reason: Missing output files: test.txt
    resources: tmpdir=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp

[Mon Nov  6 16:48:55 2023]
Error in rule make_test:
    jobid: 1
    output: test.txt

RuleException:
CalledProcessError in file C:\Users\user\data\Snakefile, line 9:
Command 'C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/mambaforge/envs/environment/python.exe "C:\Users\user\data\.snakemake\scripts\tmpnlgnh8so.create_test_txt.py"' returned non-zero exit status 1.
  File "C:\Users\user\data\Snakefile", line 9, in __rule_make_test
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\mambaforge\envs\environment\Lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 58, in run
Removing output files of failed job make_test since they might be corrupted:
test.txt
Shutting down, this might take some time.
Exiting because a job execution failed. Look above for error message
```

"environment.yaml"

```
name: environment
channels:
  - bioconda
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - ipython
  - numpy
  - pandas
  - python
  - snakemake-minimal
  - spyder
```

"environment_win10_22H2.yaml"

```
name: environment
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - bioconda
dependencies:
  - alabaster=0.7.13=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - amply=0.1.6=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - appdirs=1.4.4=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - arrow=1.3.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - astroid=2.15.8=py311h1ea47a8_0
  - asttokens=2.4.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - atomicwrites=1.4.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - attrs=23.1.0=pyh71513ae_1
  - autopep8=2.0.4=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - babel=2.13.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - backports=1.0=pyhd8ed1ab_3
  - backports.functools_lru_cache=1.6.5=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - bcrypt=4.0.1=py311hc37eb10_1
  - beautifulsoup4=4.12.2=pyha770c72_0
  - binaryornot=0.4.4=py_1
  - black=23.10.1=py311h1ea47a8_0
  - bleach=6.1.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - brotli-python=1.1.0=py311h12c1d0e_1
  - bzip2=1.0.8=h8ffe710_4
  - ca-certificates=2023.7.22=h56e8100_0
  - certifi=2023.7.22=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - cffi=1.16.0=py311ha68e1ae_0
  - chardet=5.2.0=py311h1ea47a8_1
  - charset-normalizer=3.3.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - click=8.1.7=win_pyh7428d3b_0
  - cloudpickle=3.0.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - colorama=0.4.6=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - comm=0.1.4=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - configargparse=1.7=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - connection_pool=0.0.3=pyhd3deb0d_0
  - cookiecutter=2.4.0=pyhca7485f_0
  - cryptography=41.0.5=py311h28e9c30_0
  - datrie=0.8.2=py311ha68e1ae_7
  - debugpy=1.8.0=py311h12c1d0e_1
  - decorator=5.1.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - defusedxml=0.7.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - diff-match-patch=20230430=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - dill=0.3.7=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - docstring-to-markdown=0.13=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - docutils=0.20.1=py311h1ea47a8_2
  - dpath=2.1.6=pyha770c72_0
  - entrypoints=0.4=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - exceptiongroup=1.1.3=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - executing=2.0.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - flake8=6.0.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - gettext=0.21.1=h5728263_0
  - gitdb=4.0.11=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - gitpython=3.1.40=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - glib=2.78.0=h12be248_0
  - glib-tools=2.78.0=h12be248_0
  - glpk=5.0=h8ffe710_0
  - gst-plugins-base=1.22.6=h001b923_2
  - gstreamer=1.22.6=hb4038d2_2
  - humanfriendly=10.0=py311h1ea47a8_5
  - icu=73.2=h63175ca_0
  - idna=3.4=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - imagesize=1.4.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - importlib-metadata=6.8.0=pyha770c72_0
  - importlib_metadata=6.8.0=hd8ed1ab_0
  - importlib_resources=6.1.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - inflection=0.5.1=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - intel-openmp=2023.2.0=h57928b3_50497
  - intervaltree=3.1.0=pyhd8ed1ab_1
  - ipykernel=6.26.0=pyha63f2e9_0
  - ipython=8.17.2=pyh5737063_0
  - ipython_genutils=0.2.0=py_1
  - isort=5.12.0=pyhd8ed1ab_1
  - jaraco.classes=3.3.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - jedi=0.18.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - jellyfish=1.0.1=py311hc37eb10_1
  - jinja2=3.1.2=pyhd8ed1ab_1
  - jsonschema=4.19.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - jsonschema-specifications=2023.7.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - jupyter_client=8.5.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - jupyter_core=5.5.0=py311h1ea47a8_0
  - jupyterlab_pygments=0.2.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - keyring=24.2.0=py311h1ea47a8_1
  - krb5=1.21.2=heb0366b_0
  - lazy-object-proxy=1.9.0=py311ha68e1ae_1
  - libblas=3.9.0=19_win64_mkl
  - libcblas=3.9.0=19_win64_mkl
  - libclang=15.0.7=default_h77d9078_3
  - libclang13=15.0.7=default_h77d9078_3
  - libexpat=2.5.0=h63175ca_1
  - libffi=3.4.2=h8ffe710_5
  - libglib=2.78.0=he8f3873_0
  - libhwloc=2.9.3=default_haede6df_1009
  - libiconv=1.17=h8ffe710_0
  - libjpeg-turbo=3.0.0=hcfcfb64_1
  - liblapack=3.9.0=19_win64_mkl
  - libogg=1.3.4=h8ffe710_1
  - libpng=1.6.39=h19919ed_0
  - libsodium=1.0.18=h8d14728_1
  - libspatialindex=1.9.3=h39d44d4_4
  - libsqlite=3.44.0=hcfcfb64_0
  - libvorbis=1.3.7=h0e60522_0
  - libwebp=1.3.2=hcfcfb64_1
  - libwebp-base=1.3.2=hcfcfb64_0
  - libxml2=2.11.5=hc3477c8_1
  - libzlib=1.2.13=hcfcfb64_5
  - markdown-it-py=3.0.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - markupsafe=2.1.3=py311ha68e1ae_1
  - matplotlib-inline=0.1.6=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - mccabe=0.7.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - mdurl=0.1.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - mistune=3.0.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - mkl=2023.2.0=h6a75c08_50496
  - more-itertools=10.1.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - mypy_extensions=1.0.0=pyha770c72_0
  - nbclient=0.8.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - nbconvert=7.10.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - nbconvert-core=7.10.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - nbconvert-pandoc=7.10.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - nbformat=5.9.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - nest-asyncio=1.5.8=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - numpy=1.26.0=py311h0b4df5a_0
  - numpydoc=1.5.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - openssl=3.1.4=hcfcfb64_0
  - packaging=23.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pandas=2.1.2=py311hf63dbb6_0
  - pandoc=3.1.3=h57928b3_0
  - pandocfilters=1.5.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - paramiko=3.3.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - parso=0.8.3=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pathspec=0.11.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pcre2=10.40=h17e33f8_0
  - pexpect=4.8.0=pyh1a96a4e_2
  - pickleshare=0.7.5=py_1003
  - pip=23.3.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pkgutil-resolve-name=1.3.10=pyhd8ed1ab_1
  - plac=1.4.1=pyhd8ed1ab_1
  - platformdirs=3.11.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pluggy=1.3.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - ply=3.11=py_1
  - prompt-toolkit=3.0.39=pyha770c72_0
  - prompt_toolkit=3.0.39=hd8ed1ab_0
  - psutil=5.9.5=py311ha68e1ae_1
  - pthreads-win32=2.9.1=hfa6e2cd_3
  - ptyprocess=0.7.0=pyhd3deb0d_0
  - pulp=2.7.0=py311h1ea47a8_1
  - pure_eval=0.2.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pycodestyle=2.10.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pycparser=2.21=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pydocstyle=6.3.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pyflakes=3.0.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pygments=2.16.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pylint=2.17.7=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pylint-venv=3.0.3=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pyls-spyder=0.4.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pynacl=1.5.0=py311hd53affc_3
  - pyparsing=3.1.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pyqt=5.15.9=py311h125bc19_5
  - pyqt5-sip=12.12.2=py311h12c1d0e_5
  - pyqtwebengine=5.15.9=py311h5a77453_5
  - pyreadline3=3.4.1=py311h1ea47a8_3
  - pysocks=1.7.1=pyh0701188_6
  - python=3.11.6=h2628c8c_0_cpython
  - python-dateutil=2.8.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - python-fastjsonschema=2.18.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - python-lsp-black=1.3.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - python-lsp-jsonrpc=1.1.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - python-lsp-server=1.7.4=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - python-lsp-server-base=1.7.4=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - python-slugify=8.0.1=pyhd8ed1ab_2
  - python-tzdata=2023.3=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - python_abi=3.11=4_cp311
  - pytoolconfig=1.2.5=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pytz=2023.3.post1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pywin32=306=py311h12c1d0e_2
  - pywin32-ctypes=0.2.2=py311h1ea47a8_1
  - pyyaml=6.0.1=py311ha68e1ae_1
  - pyzmq=25.1.1=py311h9250fbb_2
  - qdarkstyle=3.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - qstylizer=0.2.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - qt-main=5.15.8=h9e85ed6_17
  - qt-webengine=5.15.8=h4bf5c4e_4
  - qtawesome=1.2.3=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - qtconsole=5.4.4=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - qtconsole-base=5.4.4=pyha770c72_0
  - qtpy=2.4.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - referencing=0.30.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - requests=2.31.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - reretry=0.11.8=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - rich=13.6.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - rope=1.11.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - rpds-py=0.12.0=py311hc37eb10_0
  - rtree=1.1.0=py311hcacb13a_0
  - setuptools=68.2.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - sip=6.7.12=py311h12c1d0e_0
  - six=1.16.0=pyh6c4a22f_0
  - smart_open=6.4.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - smmap=5.0.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - snakemake-minimal=7.32.4=pyhdfd78af_1
  - snowballstemmer=2.2.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - sortedcontainers=2.4.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - soupsieve=2.5=pyhd8ed1ab_1
  - sphinx=7.2.6=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - sphinxcontrib-applehelp=1.0.7=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - sphinxcontrib-devhelp=1.0.5=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp=2.0.4=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - sphinxcontrib-jsmath=1.0.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - sphinxcontrib-qthelp=1.0.6=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml=1.1.9=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - spyder=5.4.5=py311h1ea47a8_0
  - spyder-kernels=2.4.4=win_pyh7428d3b_0
  - stack_data=0.6.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - stopit=1.1.2=py_0
  - tabulate=0.9.0=pyhd8ed1ab_1
  - tbb=2021.10.0=h91493d7_2
  - text-unidecode=1.3=pyhd8ed1ab_1
  - textdistance=4.5.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - three-merge=0.1.1=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - throttler=1.2.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - tinycss2=1.2.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - tk=8.6.13=h5226925_1
  - toml=0.10.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - tomli=2.0.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - tomlkit=0.12.2=pyha770c72_0
  - toposort=1.10=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - tornado=6.3.3=py311ha68e1ae_1
  - traitlets=5.13.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - types-python-dateutil=2.8.19.14=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - typing-extensions=4.8.0=hd8ed1ab_0
  - typing_extensions=4.8.0=pyha770c72_0
  - tzdata=2023c=h71feb2d_0
  - ucrt=10.0.22621.0=h57928b3_0
  - ujson=5.8.0=py311h12c1d0e_0
  - urllib3=2.0.7=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - vc=14.3=h64f974e_17
  - vc14_runtime=14.36.32532=hdcecf7f_17
  - vs2015_runtime=14.36.32532=h05e6639_17
  - watchdog=3.0.0=py311h1ea47a8_1
  - wcwidth=0.2.9=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - webencodings=0.5.1=pyhd8ed1ab_2
  - whatthepatch=1.0.5=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - wheel=0.41.3=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - win_inet_pton=1.1.0=pyhd8ed1ab_6
  - wrapt=1.15.0=py311ha68e1ae_1
  - xz=5.2.6=h8d14728_0
  - yaml=0.2.5=h8ffe710_2
  - yapf=0.40.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - yte=1.5.1=pyha770c72_2
  - zeromq=4.3.5=h63175ca_0
  - zipp=3.17.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - zstd=1.5.5=h12be248_0
prefix: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\mambaforge\envs\environment
```

"environment_Ubuntu22_04_3LTS.yaml"

```
name: environment
channels:
  - bioconda
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - _libgcc_mutex=0.1=conda_forge
  - _openmp_mutex=4.5=2_gnu
  - alabaster=0.7.13=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - alsa-lib=1.2.10=hd590300_0
  - amply=0.1.6=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - appdirs=1.4.4=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - arrow=1.3.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - astroid=2.15.8=py311h38be061_0
  - asttokens=2.4.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - atomicwrites=1.4.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - attr=2.5.1=h166bdaf_1
  - attrs=23.1.0=pyh71513ae_1
  - autopep8=2.0.4=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - babel=2.13.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - backports=1.0=pyhd8ed1ab_3
  - backports.functools_lru_cache=1.6.5=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - beautifulsoup4=4.12.2=pyha770c72_0
  - binaryornot=0.4.4=py_1
  - black=23.10.1=py311h38be061_0
  - bleach=6.1.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - brotli-python=1.1.0=py311hb755f60_1
  - bzip2=1.0.8=hd590300_5
  - ca-certificates=2023.7.22=hbcca054_0
  - cairo=1.18.0=h3faef2a_0
  - certifi=2023.7.22=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - cffi=1.16.0=py311hb3a22ac_0
  - chardet=5.2.0=py311h38be061_1
  - charset-normalizer=3.3.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - click=8.1.7=unix_pyh707e725_0
  - cloudpickle=3.0.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - coin-or-cbc=2.10.10=h9002f0b_0
  - coin-or-cgl=0.60.7=h516709c_0
  - coin-or-clp=1.17.8=h1ee7a9c_0
  - coin-or-osi=0.108.8=ha2443b9_0
  - coin-or-utils=2.11.9=hee58242_0
  - coincbc=2.10.10=0_metapackage
  - colorama=0.4.6=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - comm=0.1.4=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - configargparse=1.7=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - connection_pool=0.0.3=pyhd3deb0d_0
  - cookiecutter=2.4.0=pyhca7485f_0
  - cryptography=41.0.5=py311h63ff55d_0
  - datrie=0.8.2=py311h459d7ec_7
  - dbus=1.13.6=h5008d03_3
  - debugpy=1.8.0=py311hb755f60_1
  - decorator=5.1.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - defusedxml=0.7.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - diff-match-patch=20230430=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - dill=0.3.7=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - docstring-to-markdown=0.13=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - docutils=0.20.1=py311h38be061_2
  - dpath=2.1.6=pyha770c72_0
  - entrypoints=0.4=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - exceptiongroup=1.1.3=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - executing=2.0.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - expat=2.5.0=hcb278e6_1
  - flake8=6.0.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - font-ttf-dejavu-sans-mono=2.37=hab24e00_0
  - font-ttf-inconsolata=3.000=h77eed37_0
  - font-ttf-source-code-pro=2.038=h77eed37_0
  - font-ttf-ubuntu=0.83=hab24e00_0
  - fontconfig=2.14.2=h14ed4e7_0
  - fonts-conda-ecosystem=1=0
  - fonts-conda-forge=1=0
  - freetype=2.12.1=h267a509_2
  - gettext=0.21.1=h27087fc_0
  - giflib=5.2.1=h0b41bf4_3
  - gitdb=4.0.11=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - gitpython=3.1.40=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - glib=2.78.1=hfc55251_0
  - glib-tools=2.78.1=hfc55251_0
  - gmp=6.2.1=h58526e2_0
  - graphite2=1.3.13=h58526e2_1001
  - gst-plugins-base=1.22.6=h8e1006c_2
  - gstreamer=1.22.6=h98fc4e7_2
  - harfbuzz=8.2.1=h3d44ed6_0
  - humanfriendly=10.0=pyhd8ed1ab_6
  - icu=73.2=h59595ed_0
  - idna=3.4=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - imagesize=1.4.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - importlib-metadata=6.8.0=pyha770c72_0
  - importlib_metadata=6.8.0=hd8ed1ab_0
  - importlib_resources=6.1.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - inflection=0.5.1=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - intervaltree=3.1.0=pyhd8ed1ab_1
  - ipykernel=6.26.0=pyhf8b6a83_0
  - ipython=8.17.2=pyh41d4057_0
  - ipython_genutils=0.2.0=py_1
  - isort=5.12.0=pyhd8ed1ab_1
  - jaraco.classes=3.3.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - jedi=0.18.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - jeepney=0.8.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - jellyfish=2.2.10=h6bb024c_1
  - jemalloc=4.5.0=0
  - jinja2=3.1.2=pyhd8ed1ab_1
  - jsonschema=4.19.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - jsonschema-specifications=2023.7.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - jupyter_client=8.5.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - jupyter_core=5.5.0=py311h38be061_0
  - jupyterlab_pygments=0.2.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - keyring=24.2.0=py311h38be061_1
  - keyutils=1.6.1=h166bdaf_0
  - krb5=1.21.2=h659d440_0
  - lame=3.100=h166bdaf_1003
  - lazy-object-proxy=1.9.0=py311h459d7ec_1
  - ld_impl_linux-64=2.40=h41732ed_0
  - lerc=4.0.0=h27087fc_0
  - libblas=3.9.0=19_linux64_openblas
  - libcap=2.69=h0f662aa_0
  - libcblas=3.9.0=19_linux64_openblas
  - libclang=15.0.7=default_h7634d5b_3
  - libclang13=15.0.7=default_h9986a30_3
  - libcups=2.3.3=h4637d8d_4
  - libdeflate=1.19=hd590300_0
  - libedit=3.1.20191231=he28a2e2_2
  - libevent=2.1.12=hf998b51_1
  - libexpat=2.5.0=hcb278e6_1
  - libffi=3.4.2=h7f98852_5
  - libflac=1.4.3=h59595ed_0
  - libgcc=7.2.0=h69d50b8_2
  - libgcc-ng=13.2.0=h807b86a_2
  - libgcrypt=1.10.1=h166bdaf_0
  - libgfortran-ng=13.2.0=h69a702a_2
  - libgfortran5=13.2.0=ha4646dd_2
  - libglib=2.78.1=hebfc3b9_0
  - libgomp=13.2.0=h807b86a_2
  - libgpg-error=1.47=h71f35ed_0
  - libiconv=1.17=h166bdaf_0
  - libjpeg-turbo=3.0.0=hd590300_1
  - liblapack=3.9.0=19_linux64_openblas
  - liblapacke=3.9.0=19_linux64_openblas
  - libllvm15=15.0.7=h5cf9203_3
  - libnsl=2.0.1=hd590300_0
  - libogg=1.3.4=h7f98852_1
  - libopenblas=0.3.24=pthreads_h413a1c8_0
  - libopus=1.3.1=h7f98852_1
  - libpng=1.6.39=h753d276_0
  - libpq=16.0=hfc447b1_1
  - libsndfile=1.2.2=hc60ed4a_1
  - libsodium=1.0.18=h36c2ea0_1
  - libspatialindex=1.9.3=h9c3ff4c_4
  - libsqlite=3.44.0=h2797004_0
  - libstdcxx-ng=13.2.0=h7e041cc_2
  - libsystemd0=254=h3516f8a_0
  - libtiff=4.6.0=ha9c0a0a_2
  - libuuid=2.38.1=h0b41bf4_0
  - libvorbis=1.3.7=h9c3ff4c_0
  - libwebp=1.3.2=h658648e_1
  - libwebp-base=1.3.2=hd590300_0
  - libxcb=1.15=h0b41bf4_0
  - libxkbcommon=1.6.0=h5d7e998_0
  - libxml2=2.11.5=h232c23b_1
  - libzlib=1.2.13=hd590300_5
  - lz4-c=1.9.4=hcb278e6_0
  - markdown-it-py=3.0.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - markupsafe=2.1.3=py311h459d7ec_1
  - matplotlib-inline=0.1.6=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - mccabe=0.7.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - mdurl=0.1.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - mistune=3.0.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - more-itertools=10.1.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - mpg123=1.32.3=h59595ed_0
  - mypy_extensions=1.0.0=pyha770c72_0
  - mysql-common=8.0.33=hf1915f5_6
  - mysql-libs=8.0.33=hca2cd23_6
  - nbclient=0.8.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - nbconvert=7.10.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - nbconvert-core=7.10.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - nbconvert-pandoc=7.10.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - nbformat=5.9.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - ncurses=6.4=h59595ed_2
  - nest-asyncio=1.5.8=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - nspr=4.35=h27087fc_0
  - nss=3.94=h1d7d5a4_0
  - numpy=1.26.0=py311h64a7726_0
  - numpydoc=1.5.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - openssl=3.1.4=hd590300_0
  - packaging=23.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pandas=2.1.2=py311h320fe9a_0
  - pandoc=3.1.3=h32600fe_0
  - pandocfilters=1.5.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - parso=0.8.3=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pathspec=0.11.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pcre2=10.40=hc3806b6_0
  - pexpect=4.8.0=pyh1a96a4e_2
  - pickleshare=0.7.5=py_1003
  - pip=23.3.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pixman=0.42.2=h59595ed_0
  - pkgutil-resolve-name=1.3.10=pyhd8ed1ab_1
  - plac=1.4.1=pyhd8ed1ab_1
  - platformdirs=3.11.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pluggy=1.3.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - ply=3.11=py_1
  - prompt-toolkit=3.0.39=pyha770c72_0
  - prompt_toolkit=3.0.39=hd8ed1ab_0
  - psutil=5.9.5=py311h459d7ec_1
  - pthread-stubs=0.4=h36c2ea0_1001
  - ptyprocess=0.7.0=pyhd3deb0d_0
  - pulp=2.7.0=py311h38be061_1
  - pulseaudio-client=16.1=hb77b528_5
  - pure_eval=0.2.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pycodestyle=2.10.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pycparser=2.21=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pydocstyle=6.3.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pyflakes=3.0.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pygments=2.16.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pylint=2.17.7=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pylint-venv=3.0.3=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pyls-spyder=0.4.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pyparsing=3.1.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pyqt=5.15.9=py311hf0fb5b6_5
  - pyqt5-sip=12.12.2=py311hb755f60_5
  - pyqtwebengine=5.15.9=py311hd529140_5
  - pysocks=1.7.1=pyha2e5f31_6
  - python=3.11.6=hab00c5b_0_cpython
  - python-dateutil=2.8.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - python-fastjsonschema=2.18.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - python-lsp-black=1.3.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - python-lsp-jsonrpc=1.1.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - python-lsp-server=1.7.4=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - python-lsp-server-base=1.7.4=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - python-slugify=8.0.1=pyhd8ed1ab_2
  - python-tzdata=2023.3=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - python_abi=3.11=4_cp311
  - pytoolconfig=1.2.5=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pytz=2023.3.post1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pyxdg=0.28=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pyyaml=6.0.1=py311h459d7ec_1
  - pyzmq=25.1.1=py311h34ded2d_2
  - qdarkstyle=3.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - qstylizer=0.2.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - qt-main=5.15.8=h82b777d_17
  - qt-webengine=5.15.8=h75ea521_4
  - qtawesome=1.2.3=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - qtconsole=5.4.4=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - qtconsole-base=5.4.4=pyha770c72_0
  - qtpy=2.4.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - readline=8.2=h8228510_1
  - referencing=0.30.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - requests=2.31.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - reretry=0.11.8=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - rich=13.6.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - rope=1.11.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - rpds-py=0.12.0=py311h46250e7_0
  - rtree=1.1.0=py311h3bb2b0f_0
  - secretstorage=3.3.3=py311h38be061_2
  - setuptools=68.2.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - sip=6.7.12=py311hb755f60_0
  - six=1.16.0=pyh6c4a22f_0
  - smart_open=6.4.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - smmap=5.0.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - snakemake-minimal=7.32.4=pyhdfd78af_1
  - snowballstemmer=2.2.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - sortedcontainers=2.4.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - soupsieve=2.5=pyhd8ed1ab_1
  - sphinx=7.2.6=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - sphinxcontrib-applehelp=1.0.7=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - sphinxcontrib-devhelp=1.0.5=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp=2.0.4=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - sphinxcontrib-jsmath=1.0.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - sphinxcontrib-qthelp=1.0.6=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml=1.1.9=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - spyder=5.4.5=py311h38be061_0
  - spyder-kernels=2.4.4=unix_pyh707e725_0
  - stack_data=0.6.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - stopit=1.1.2=py_0
  - tabulate=0.9.0=pyhd8ed1ab_1
  - text-unidecode=1.3=pyhd8ed1ab_1
  - textdistance=4.5.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - three-merge=0.1.1=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - throttler=1.2.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - tinycss2=1.2.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - tk=8.6.13=noxft_h4845f30_101
  - toml=0.10.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - tomli=2.0.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - tomlkit=0.12.2=pyha770c72_0
  - toposort=1.10=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - tornado=6.3.3=py311h459d7ec_1
  - traitlets=5.13.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - types-python-dateutil=2.8.19.14=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - typing-extensions=4.8.0=hd8ed1ab_0
  - typing_extensions=4.8.0=pyha770c72_0
  - tzdata=2023c=h71feb2d_0
  - ujson=5.8.0=py311hb755f60_0
  - urllib3=2.0.7=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - watchdog=3.0.0=py311h38be061_1
  - wcwidth=0.2.9=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - webencodings=0.5.1=pyhd8ed1ab_2
  - whatthepatch=1.0.5=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - wheel=0.41.3=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - wrapt=1.15.0=py311h459d7ec_1
  - wurlitzer=3.0.3=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - xcb-util=0.4.0=hd590300_1
  - xcb-util-image=0.4.0=h8ee46fc_1
  - xcb-util-keysyms=0.4.0=h8ee46fc_1
  - xcb-util-renderutil=0.3.9=hd590300_1
  - xcb-util-wm=0.4.1=h8ee46fc_1
  - xkeyboard-config=2.40=hd590300_0
  - xorg-compositeproto=0.4.2=h7f98852_1001
  - xorg-damageproto=1.2.1=h7f98852_1002
  - xorg-fixesproto=5.0=h7f98852_1002
  - xorg-inputproto=2.3.2=h7f98852_1002
  - xorg-kbproto=1.0.7=h7f98852_1002
  - xorg-libice=1.1.1=hd590300_0
  - xorg-libsm=1.2.4=h7391055_0
  - xorg-libx11=1.8.7=h8ee46fc_0
  - xorg-libxau=1.0.11=hd590300_0
  - xorg-libxcomposite=0.4.6=h0b41bf4_1
  - xorg-libxdamage=1.1.5=h7f98852_1
  - xorg-libxdmcp=1.1.3=h7f98852_0
  - xorg-libxext=1.3.4=h0b41bf4_2
  - xorg-libxfixes=5.0.3=h7f98852_1004
  - xorg-libxi=1.7.10=h7f98852_0
  - xorg-libxrandr=1.5.2=h7f98852_1
  - xorg-libxrender=0.9.11=hd590300_0
  - xorg-libxtst=1.2.3=h7f98852_1002
  - xorg-randrproto=1.5.0=h7f98852_1001
  - xorg-recordproto=1.14.2=h7f98852_1002
  - xorg-renderproto=0.11.1=h7f98852_1002
  - xorg-util-macros=1.19.3=h7f98852_0
  - xorg-xextproto=7.3.0=h0b41bf4_1003
  - xorg-xf86vidmodeproto=2.3.1=h7f98852_1002
  - xorg-xproto=7.0.31=h7f98852_1007
  - xz=5.2.6=h166bdaf_0
  - yaml=0.2.5=h7f98852_2
  - yapf=0.40.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - yte=1.5.1=pyha770c72_2
  - zeromq=4.3.5=h59595ed_0
  - zipp=3.17.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - zlib=1.2.13=hd590300_5
  - zstd=1.5.5=hfc55251_0
```